# How to solve error 500 when doing http queries with laravel 5.5 and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, http

When doing update or delete it shows me in console 500 (internal server error)

Do I need to change my routes or my js?

I have already added to my JS the header that laravel indicates in its documentation to pass the tokens and I have added the meta token to the header of my page.

I have also passed the token, id and method in the data of my ajax

I have put all the methods in the ajax and it throws me the same results it only changes the method, but it throws the same error 500

And in all these errors the log does not show anything, only the chrome console does where I'm working

**Controller**

```
public function destroy(Request $request,$id)
{

    dd($request->ajax());
    if($request->ajax()){
        $item = UserMenu::destroy($id);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => $item->name. ' Fue eliminado'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
{!!Form::open(['route'=> 
['items.destroy',$m->usermenus_id],'method'=>'DELETE'])!!}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-delete btn-danger" aria-hidden="true"data-id="{{$m->usermenus_id}}">Delete</button>
 {!!Form::close()!!}
```

**ajax.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$('#alert').hide();
$('.btn-delete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log();

    if(! confirm('¿Esta seguro que quiere eliminar?')) return false;

    var row = $(this).parents('tr');
    let id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    let form = $(this).parents('form');
    var method=form.attr("method");
    var url = form.attr("action");
    let formu = form.serializeArray();
    console.log("url "+url+" method "+method);
    $('#alert').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: url,
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {formu,"id": id,
            _method: 'DELETE'},

        success: function (data) {
            row.fadeOut;
            $('#alert').css("display", "block");
            $('#alert').addClass('alert-success');
            $('#alert').html('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+data.message);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#alert').css("display", "block");
            $('#alert').addClass('alert-danger');
            $('#alert').html('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> Algo salió mal');
        }
    });

});
});
```

**route**

```
Route::resource('items','UserMenuItemsController');
```

**Console network**

```
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9660;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '&#9654;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } if (doc.createEvent && s.dispatchEvent) { var event = doc.createEvent('Event'); event.initEvent('sf-dump-expanded' === newClass ? 'sfbeforedumpexpand' : 'sfbeforedumpcollapse', true, false); s.dispatchEvent(event); } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = s.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-(compact|expanded)\b/, newClass); if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (-1 == a[s].className.indexOf(newClass)) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; function collapse(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function expand(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function collapseAll(root) { var a = root.querySelector('a.sf-dump-toggle'); if (a) { collapse(a, true); expand(a); return true; } return false; } function reveal(node) { var previous, parents = []; while ((node = node.parentNode || {}) && (previous = node.previousSibling) && 'A' === previous.tagName) { parents.push(previous); } if (0 !== parents.length) { parents.forEach(function (parent) { expand(parent); }); return true; } return false; } function highlight(root, activeNode, nodes) { resetHighlightedNodes(root); Array.from(nodes||[]).forEach(function (node) { if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/.test(node.className)) { node.className = node.className + ' sf-dump-highlight'; } }); if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/.test(activeNode.className)) { activeNode.className = activeNode.className + ' sf-dump-highlight-active'; } } function resetHighlightedNodes(root) { Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str, .sf-dump-key, .sf-dump-public, .sf-dump-protected, .sf-dump-private')).forEach(function (strNode) { strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/, ''); strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/, ''); }); } return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), options = {"maxDepth":1,"maxStringLength":160,"fileLinkFormat":false}, elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, s, h, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); for (i in x) { options[i] = x[i]; } function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } else if (e.target.nextElementSibling && 'A' == e.target.nextElementSibling.tagName) { f(e.target.nextElementSibling, e, true); } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } function xpathString(str) { var parts = str.match(/[^'"]+|['"]/g).map(function (part) { if ("'" == part) { return '"\'"'; } if ('"' == part) { return "'\"'"; } return "'" + part + "'"; }); return "concat(" + parts.join(",") + ", '')"; } function xpathHasClass(className) { return "contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' " + className +" ')"; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a, e, c) { if (c) { e.target.style.cursor = "pointer"; } else if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click', function (a, e, c) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r = doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s = r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode; t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f = f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t = t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) { r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc, '\\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(r.className)) { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (c) { } else if (doc.getSelection) { try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) { doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-str-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); e = a.parentNode.parentNode; e.className = e.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-str-(expand|collapse)\b/, a.parentNode.className); } }); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; if ('SAMP' == elt.tagName) { a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; } a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all children'; a.innerHTML += '<span>&#9660;</span>'; a.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; x = 1; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { x += elt.parentNode.getAttribute('data-depth')/1; } elt.setAttribute('data-depth', x); var className = elt.className; elt.className = 'sf-dump-expanded'; if (className ? 'sf-dump-expanded' !== className : (x > options.maxDepth)) { toggle(a); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-ref\b/.test(elt.className) && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { s = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' <span>&#9654;</span>'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '<span>&#9654;</span>'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '&hellip;'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } } if (doc.evaluate && Array.from && root.children.length > 1) { root.setAttribute('tabindex', 0); SearchState = function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }; SearchState.prototype = { next: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx < (this.nodes.length - 1) ? this.idx + 1 : 0; return this.current(); }, previous: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx > 0 ? this.idx - 1 : (this.nodes.length - 1); return this.current(); }, isEmpty: function () { return 0 === this.count(); }, current: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return null; } return this.nodes[this.idx]; }, reset: function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }, count: function () { return this.nodes.length; }, }; function showCurrent(state) { var currentNode = state.current(); if (currentNode) { reveal(currentNode); highlight(root, currentNode, state.nodes); } counter.textContent = (state.isEmpty() ? 0 : state.idx + 1) + ' of ' + state.count(); } var search = doc.createElement('div'); search.className = 'sf-dump-search-wrapper sf-dump-search-hidden'; search.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" class="sf-dump-search-input"> <span class="sf-dump-search-count">0 of 0<\/span> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-previous" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M1683 1331l-166 165q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-531-531-531 531q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-166-165q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l742-741q19-19 45-19t45 19l742 741q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/> <\/svg> <\/button> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-next" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M1683 808l-742 741q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-742-741q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l166-165q19-19 45-19t45 19l531 531 531-531q19-19 45-19t45 19l166 165q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/> <\/svg> <\/button> '; root.insertBefore(search, root.firstChild); var state = new SearchState(); var searchInput = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-input'); var counter = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-count'); var searchInputTimer = 0; var previousSearchQuery = ''; addEventListener(searchInput, 'keyup', function (e) { var searchQuery = e.target.value; /* Don't perform anything if the pressed key didn't change the query */ if (searchQuery === previousSearchQuery) { return; } previousSearchQuery = searchQuery; clearTimeout(searchInputTimer); searchInputTimer = setTimeout(function () { state.reset(); collapseAll(root); resetHighlightedNodes(root); if ('' === searchQuery) { counter.textContent = '0 of 0'; return; } var classMatches = [ "sf-dump-str", "sf-dump-key", "sf-dump-public", "sf-dump-protected", "sf-dump-private", ].map(xpathHasClass).join(' or '); var xpathResult = doc.evaluate('.//span[' + classMatches + '][contains(translate(child::text(), ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toUpperCase()) + ', ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) + '), ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) + ')]', root, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null); while (node = xpathResult.iterateNext()) state.nodes.push(node); showCurrent(state); }, 400); }); Array.from(search.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-search-input-next, .sf-dump-search-input-previous')).forEach(function (btn) { addEventListener(btn, 'click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); -1 !== e.target.className.indexOf('next') ? state.next() : state.previous(); searchInput.focus(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); }) }); addEventListener(root, 'keydown', function (e) { var isSearchActive = !/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/.test(search.className); if ((114 === e.keyCode && !isSearchActive) || (isCtrlKey(e) && 70 === e.keyCode)) { /* F3 or CMD/CTRL + F */ e.preventDefault(); search.className = search.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/, ''); searchInput.focus(); } else if (isSearchActive) { if (27 === e.keyCode) { /* ESC key */ search.className += ' sf-dump-search-hidden'; e.preventDefault(); resetHighlightedNodes(root); searchInput.value = ''; } else if ( (isCtrlKey(e) && 71 === e.keyCode) /* CMD/CTRL + G */ || 13 === e.keyCode /* Enter */ || 114 === e.keyCode /* F3 */ ) { e.preventDefault(); e.shiftKey ? state.previous() : state.next(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); } } }); } if (0 >= options.maxStringLength) { return; } try { elt = root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str'); len = elt.length; i = 0; t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; s = elt.innerText || elt.textContent; x = s.length - options.maxStringLength; if (0 < x) { h = elt.innerHTML; elt[elt.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent'] = s.substring(0, options.maxStringLength); elt.className += ' sf-dump-str-collapse'; elt.innerHTML = '<span class=sf-dump-str-collapse>'+h+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="Collapse"> &#9664;</a></span>'+ '<span class=sf-dump-str-expand>'+elt.innerHTML+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="'+x+' remaining characters"> &#9654;</a></span>'; } } } catch (e) { } }; })(document); </script><style> pre.sf-dump { display: block; white-space: pre; padding: 5px; } pre.sf-dump:after { content: ""; visibility: hidden; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; } pre.sf-dump span { display: inline; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact { display: none; } pre.sf-dump abbr { text-decoration: none; border: none; cursor: help; } pre.sf-dump a { text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; border: 0; outline: none; color: inherit; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis { display: inline-block; overflow: visible; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-width: 5em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: top; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis+.sf-dump-ellipsis { max-width: none; } pre.sf-dump code { display:inline; padding:0; background:none; } .sf-dump-str-collapse .sf-dump-str-collapse { display: none; } .sf-dump-str-expand .sf-dump-str-expand { display: none; } .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight { background: rgba(111, 172, 204, 0.3); border: 1px solid #7DA0B1; border-radius: 3px; } .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight-active { background: rgba(253, 175, 0, 0.4); border: 1px solid #ffa500; border-radius: 3px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-hidden { display: none; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper { float: right; font-size: 0; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 100%; text-align: right; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > * { vertical-align: top; box-sizing: border-box; height: 21px; font-weight: normal; border-radius: 0; background: #FFF; color: #757575; border: 1px solid #BBB; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > input.sf-dump-search-input { padding: 3px; height: 21px; font-size: 12px; border-right: none; width: 140px; border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; color: #000; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-previous { background: #F2F2F2; outline: none; border-left: none; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next { border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next > svg, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-previous > svg { pointer-events: none; width: 12px; height: 12px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-count { display: inline-block; padding: 0 5px; margin: 0; border-left: none; line-height: 21px; font-size: 12px; }pre.sf-dump, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-default{background-color:#fff; color:#222; line-height:1.2em; font-weight:normal; font:12px Monaco, Consolas, monospace; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap; position:relative; z-index:100000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-num{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-const{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-str{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-cchr{color:#222}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-note{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ref{color:#a0a0a0}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-public{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-protected{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-private{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-meta{color:#b729d9}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-key{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-index{color:#a71d5d}</style><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1977966324 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str>1</span>"
```

Sfdump("sf-dump-1977966324")

[image]

I hope to receive a request in my controller and that is why it has the dd at the beginning, but I only receive the error:

> PUT http://localhost:8000/items/1 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> PUT, DELETE, POST, HEAD, GET AND PATCH

Comment: if you open the *network* tab which is next to *console* tab, then make a request, you can see some more details about the error

Comment: in your *home.blade.php* there is `$m>usermenus_id` what is this? do you mean `$m->usermenus_id`?

Comment: Fixed the home, it was a mistake to paste.
And there place the network response of that error.

Comment: not the javascript file, I meant to make a request to items/1 then select the corresponding request (I think it's called 1 in your network tab and it must be in red color) then you will see some more tabs like "Headers, Preview, and Response", check the response tab please

Comment: That's what it shows, attach image of the 3 tabs

Comment: change `dd($request->ajax());` to something other like `return 'test';` or maybe `return $requet->ajax();` and test it again please. actually you are making an ajax request and `dd` in php which won't show the result as you expected.

Comment: It is correct what you say, and I tell you my results.

return "true": enter the success of the ajax.

return $ request-> ajax (): generate error 500

return true: generates the 500 error

Comment: so with `return $request->ajax()` check *network* tab to see the more details about the error. I think it's because of *Request* class, you may need to change your call to `if(request()->ajax())`. I mean you're importing the wrong Request class.

Comment: Yes, I had that before and when I removed the dd if I entered, but apparently I have a problem with my query because when doing the destroy ($ id) it generates the 500 error code

And validate and $ id if it is equal to the id that I am sending

Comment: Using `dd()` will return a 500 error. If you remove (or comment out all uses or `dd()`) in the request then the actual 500 error will be returned in the response. Please could you add that response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to eliminate the dd so you can do the process normally.